# Using rspec to confirm a function is called within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to confirm a function was called in a controller method with an rspec test. To do this, I'm following the relishapp documentation for [confirming an instance of a class receives a message](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class).  My implementation is as follows:However, I keep getting the following error:

```
  it "does the job" do
    expect {
      post :create, {:obj => valid_attributes}
    }.to change(Object, :count).by(1)
    Object.any_instance.should_receive(:delay)
    flash[:notice].should eq(I18n.t(:success, obj: 'object', past_participle: 'created'))
    response.should redirect_to(new_object_path)
  end
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: delay
```

In this case, I'm trying to confirm the `delay` method was called.  I can clearly see the method is called in the controller method, why doesn't rspec confirm it?

Comment: Place your should_receive call before you make the post request.

Comment: That actually stops the spec from passing at all.  I now get different errors based on what method I check for, but the controller method never works.  See an elaboration on the errors in this pastie: http://pastie.org/private/yvvanhw95fnrercqth9ugg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, there are two ways to approach testing this behavior.

You could ignore the delaying of `cio_register()` method when testing, as Delayed Job documentation suggests, with `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false`. I believe this is because we can safely assume that Delayed Job will work.

I would re-write the tests as follows:

```
describe '#create'
  it 'creates a new Object' do
    expect {
      post :create, {:object => valid_attributes}
    }.to change(Object, :count).by(1)
  end

  it 'performs CIO registration on new object' do
    # Skip Delayed Jobs.
    original_setting = Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs
    Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false

    # Our expectation.
    Object.any_instance.should_receive(:cio_register)

    post :create, {:object => valid_attributes}

    # Restore Delayed Job's setting.
    Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = original_setting
  end

  it 'sets appropriate flash message'
  it 'redirects to path showing details of newly created Object'
end
```

If the delaying is critical to the behavior of the method, you could work the job in the test and ensure its result:

```
it 'performs CIO registration on new object' do
  # Our expectation.
  Object.any_instance.should_receive(:cio_register)

  post :create, {:object => valid_attributes}

  # Let's process the delayed job.
  Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
end
```

I found this interesting entry while googling: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/08/16/testing-with-delayed-jobs/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check the Delayed Jobs documentation about specialized testing.

Comment: Also, for anyone who comes across this, I used the second code snippet